# How to select the individual div when i click

Tags: jquery

Ive been trying to get this result :

- Click on a tag(the arrow) and activate the css "active" on individual img tag(dots).

How do i do that? The end product is like a slider image with dots at the bottom.

```js
$(".slideshow-container a").click(function(){
var clickableImg = $(this).parent().children("div.dot").children(".clickableImg");
if ($(this).hasClass("prev")) {
  $(".dot img.active").removeClass("active");
  $(clickableImg).addClass("active");
}if ($(this).hasClass("next")){
  $(".staticImg img.active").removeClass("active");
    $(clickableImg).addClass("active")
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow-container">
      <div class="slide">
        <div class="grid_container">
        <div><img src=""></div>
        <div><p>Text Here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  
    <div class="dot">
    <img id="dot1" class="clickableImg imageNum active" src="" alt="">
    <img id="dot2" class="clickableImg imageNum" src="" alt="">
    <img id="dot3" class="clickableImg imageNum" src="" alt="">
    <img id="dot4" class="clickableImg imageNum"  src="" alt="">
    </div>

      <a id="prev" class="prev">&#10094;</a>
      <a id="next" class="next">&#10095;</a>

    </div>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. When you click the right-arrow, which images do you want to add the "active" class to? When you click the left-arrow, which images do you want to remove the "active" class from? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71477095/edit) to describe in more detail what behavior you are expecting.

Comment: to add and remove the class active on all the img inside the div class dot. so if i click right the second img has active class, click right again third img has active class. and has infinite loop so call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things here:

- In this case it is better to use `button` tags for your `prev` and `next` elements with the type attribute set to button.
- You need to keep track of the current visible element in some way. The example below uses a global variable.
- Depending on the implementation it may make sense to separate the event handlers for `prev` and `next` since they require slightly different logic to make sure we can restart when we reach the end/beginning of the slideshow.
- You may be able to use jQuery `show/hide` functions instead of CSS classes depending on what the initial state should be.

Below is one possible implementation:

```js
var totalItemCount = $("[id^=dot]").length; // wildcard CSS selector
var currentIndex = 1;

$(".slideshow-container #prev").click(function () {
  $("#dot" + currentIndex).removeClass("active").addClass("hidden");
  decrement();
  $("#dot" + currentIndex).addClass("active");
  $(".slide p").text($("#dot" + currentIndex).data("src"));
});

$(".slideshow-container #next").click(function () {
  $("#dot" + currentIndex).removeClass("active").addClass("hidden");
  increment();
  $("#dot" + currentIndex).addClass("active");
  $(".slide p").text($("#dot" + currentIndex).data("src"));
});

function increment() {
  // restart from start if we reach last element
  if (currentIndex + 1 > totalItemCount) {
    currentIndex = 1;
  }
  else {
      currentIndex++;
  }  
}

function decrement() {
  // restart from end if we reach first element
  if (currentIndex - 1 <= 0) {
    currentIndex = totalItemCount;
  }
  else {
    currentIndex--;
  }  
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="slide">
    <p>Initial Emoji Here </p>
  </div>
  <div class="dots">
    <span id="dot1" class="active" data-src="">one</span>
    <span id="dot2" class="hidden" data-src="">two</span>
    <span id="dot3" class="hidden" data-src="">three</span>
    <span id="dot4" class="hidden" data-src="">four</span>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="prev" class="prev">&#10094;</button>
  <button type="button" id="next" class="next">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The next and prev controls the main image <div class="slide">
        <div class="grid_container">
        <div><img src=""></div>
        <div><p>Text Here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

Comment: I've updated the example and added a `.slide p` element that gets updated when clicking on the controls. There is multiple ways to store the source for your images, the example here uses a custom data attribute whose value we read with the jQuery `data` function.